# If everything is Mithya as per Advaita, are Vedas Mithya too?

Tags: vedas, advaita, brahman

Advaita Vedanta says that everything is Mithya and Brahman is the only truth. Are not the Vedas Mithya too? How can true knowledge be attained by Vedic statements?

Comment: The word Mithya has terminological usage within the framework of Advaita .. see this answer --- https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/35926/4732

Comment: The disparity is due to the order of reality . Sri Bharati Theertha Swami (Sringeri) would quote from Shruti  ***Yatra Veda Aveda Bhavanti*** .(From Paramarthmik point of view ,Vedas are also Mithya , notwithstanding that to be the pramana for *Brahman is the only truth*).Vedanta resolutely agrees  with the Pramana of Vedas , (athirikth pramana , apart from direct perception pratyaksha) .Here, Swamiji cites the analogy of Trijatas swapna in Ramayana. Although the swapna is in a different order of reality it gives the cue on what could happen in another order of reality ( swapna shaastra).

Comment: Similarly Vedas can only give a cue (jnana) that Brahman is the only truth. But the experience (vijnanana) transcends Veda vakyas.

Commentary on BG 2.16 details the concept of  Mityatva .

https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/52421/what-verse-of-bhagavat-gita-according-to-scholars-explicitly-favour-advaitic-in/52470#52470